# No me deja importar matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-import, python-3.8

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en python y necesito importar matplotlib
pero al hacerlo me aparece un error diciendo "MODULENOTFOUNDERROR" mi versión es la 3.8. 
No tengo experiencia en este lenguaje. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido @MauricioMontiel a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), favoreciendo así tus chances de obtener una buena recepción por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: Es posible que tengas dos versiones de python instaladas en tu máquina... mi sugerencia como estás empezando a programar es instalar anaconda para que allanes un poco la gestión de bibliotecas en python, hay un buen tutorial sobre ello aca https://www.tutorialpython.com/instalar-python/ es un buen comienzo para que no te desanimes en esta parte inicial suerte!!!

Comment: Puedes instalarlo usando `pip3 install -U matplotlib`.                                                    
Como dijo Hubert: _No te desanimes_ **:)**

Comment: En caso de que no tengas instalado el gestor de paquetes **pip** puedes seguir esta guía: [Instalar PIP](https://www.neoguias.com/como-instalar-pip-python/)

Answer (score 1):

@MauricioMuntiel , como dice lxndr-rl

Primero debes tener instalado el gestor de paquetes pip, esto lo puedes hacer con la siguiente instrucción desde cmd:

> python -m pip install -U pip

Una vez instalado el gestor de paquetes para Python debes instalar Matplotlib con la siguiente instrucción:

> python -m pip install -U matplotlib

Una vez echo esto ya deberías poder importar tu librería sin problemas.

Aquí te dejo el link en caso de que necesites más información:
[Matplotlib 3.x] - https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html

Saludos.